# how to use word vba to read header's text on last page?

Tags: vba, ms-word, header

Firstly, I make a WORD doc with 2 pages.

Then, I add a header like

```
Current {page}, total {numpages}
```

where `{page}` and `{numpages}` are field codes. So `Currnet 1, total 2` is shown on the first page, while `Currnet 2, total 2` is shown on the 2nd page.

My question is, how can we read the header's text on **last** page, in my case, which should be `Currnet 2, total 2`.

I can but only write

```
Sub a()

    MsgBox ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text
    
End Sub
```

which can only read the text on first page, i.e. `Currnet 1, total 2`.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
Sub GetLastPageHeader()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Selection.Range
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
With ActiveWindow
  If .View.SplitSpecial <> wdPaneNone Then .Panes(2).Close
  .ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
  .ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
  .ActivePane.Selection.MoveEndUntil vbCr, wdForward
  MsgBox Selection.Text
  .ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekMainDocument
End With
Rng.Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

To get the last page header for the current Section, replace:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=ActiveDocument.ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
```

with:

```
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Count:=ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Sections(1).Range.End).ComputeStatistics(wdStatisticPages)
```

Comment: Thanks, the code treat word doc with 1 section. What if there are multiple sections, and all section has its own header text?

Comment: Your question was about the last page in the *Document*. Regardless of how many Sections the document has, the macro returns the last page header in the *Document*. See updated reply re the last page header for the current *Section*.

Comment: It really solved my problem which I have searched for hints and be confused for a long time. Thank you.

Comment: @oyster - whilst that may give you the text in the header it still doesn't tell you whether the page total has been typed in. To really solve your problem, you need to look for the field codes in the last section header.

Comment: Agreed - and the code could easily be modified to do that. That said, the code I posted isn't ideal for that purpose - one really needs to loop through all headers without regard to the section and what the last page might be (since we don't necessarly know in advance which headers are active and which might occur on the any given page of the document).

Comment: it is enough to extract the header then tell the user to check whether it is right

Comment: here is a more complex case I met https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72752268/how-to-use-word-vba-to-read-header-mixed-with-text-and-shape-on-last-page-of-v

Answer (score 1):

To get a report on every used Header & footer, you might use something like:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, Sctn As Section, HdFt As HeaderFooter, Fld As Field, StrHdFt As String
With ActiveDocument
  For Each Sctn In .Sections
    For Each HdFt In Sctn.Headers
      With HdFt
        If .Exists Then
          Select Case .Index
            Case wdHeaderFooterEvenPages: StrHdFt = "Section: " & Sctn.Index & ", Even Pages Header" & vbCr & vbCr & "Fields:"
            Case wdHeaderFooterFirstPage: StrHdFt = "Section: " & Sctn.Index & ", First Page Header" & vbCr & vbCr & "Fields:"
            Case wdHeaderFooterPrimary: StrHdFt = "Section: " & Sctn.Index & ", Primary Header" & vbCr & vbCr & "Fields:"
          End Select
          For Each Fld In .Range.Fields
            With Fld
              Select Case .Type
                Case wdFieldNumPages, wdFieldPage, wdFieldSection, wdFieldSectionPages
                  StrHdFt = StrHdFt & vbCr & "{" & .Code.Text & "}"
                Case Else
              End Select
            End With
          Next
          MsgBox "Text: " & .Range.Text & vbCr & StrHdFt
        End If
      End With
    Next
    For Each HdFt In Sctn.Footers
      With HdFt
        If .Exists Then
          Select Case .Index
            Case wdHeaderFooterEvenPages: StrHdFt = "Section: " & Sctn.Index & ", Even Pages Footer" & vbCr & vbCr & "Fields:"
            Case wdHeaderFooterFirstPage: StrHdFt = "Section: " & Sctn.Index & ", First Page Footer" & vbCr & vbCr & "Fields:"
            Case wdHeaderFooterPrimary: StrHdFt = "Section: " & Sctn.Index & ", Primary Footer" & vbCr & vbCr & "Fields:"
          End Select
          For Each Fld In .Range.Fields
            With Fld
              Select Case .Type
                Case wdFieldNumPages, wdFieldPage, wdFieldSection, wdFieldSectionPages
                  StrHdFt = StrHdFt & vbCr & "{" & .Code.Text & "}"
                Case Else
              End Select
            End With
          Next
          MsgBox "Text: " & .Range.Text & vbCr & StrHdFt
        End If
      End With
    Next
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Don't worry that the text string is only for the first page in each Header/Footer in each Section. What matters is that the required fields are present.

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

But, if you want to get the number of the last page of the document you can use

```
ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Information(wdActiveEndPageNumber)
```

And to get the number of pages

```
ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
```

Comment: So bad. In fact, I want to read and check wheter the information on last page is right. In other words, somebody does not use field to calculate `total page` but he writes the number by hand. So sometimes, I meet the header says `current 2, total 3 pages` for a 2-page doc file.

Comment: The thing is, the header is not really "on" any page. It is a section property. You could, in vba, find the total number of pages and find what text is in the **headers** for the last section. (Each section has three headers, any one of which might be displaying on a particular page. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/sections2007.htm#Recap_of_Header/Footer_settings)

Comment: @oyster - so you need to check the last section, not the last page, and look for the fieldcodes