# how to use word vba to read header, mixed with text and shape, on last page of very section?

Tags: vba, ms-word, header

I have just asked a similar question as [how to use word vba to read header's text on last page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703530/how-to-use-word-vba-to-read-headers-text-on-last-page). macropod supplied a soltuion, thanks

However, so bad, I meet doc which mixes text and shape in the header, and the useful information is actually in shape. I made a simplified version `mix_txt_shape_in_header.docx` and put it on https://github.com/retsyo/study_vba_doc

For this doc, what I expected is to extract all displayed text( so it should be text + text_in_shape) on last page in every section, and prompt something like

```
Index page i of i

Main part page 2 of 32
```

After study macropod's code, I think if I can `select` the shape in the header, I can read the information. But soon I meet 3 questions

1. how to `select` the shape

I record a vba code while I operate on shape in header, and find that shape's name is used in the vba, for example

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("TextBox 1").Select
```

obviously, it is not applicable because I can't know shape's name in advance.

And even I know the name and write

```vb
ActiveDocument.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

or

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
```

I get error message

```
invalid use of attribute
```

2. for the reason I stated above, I can't figure out how to get the text of shape, which is on the last page of every section. Here is what I get as far as I can

```
Sub getShapeNumber()
    NumSections = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
    For idxsec = 1 To NumSections
        numShape = ActiveDocument.Sections(idxsec).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.Count
        For idxShape = 1 To numShape
    txt = "section " & idxsec & ", shape " & numShape & ": "
            txt = txt & ActiveDocument.Sections(idxsec).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(idxShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
            Debug.Print txt
        Next
        Debug.Print "====="
    Next
End Sub
```

However it says

```
section 1, shape 4: 
section 1, shape 4: page i of  i
section 1, shape 4:                          <-- why this shape is here
section 1, shape 4: page 1 of  32            <-- why this shape is here
=====

section 2, shape 4:                          <-- why this shape is here
section 2, shape 4: page i of  i             <-- why this shape is here
section 2, shape 4: 
section 2, shape 4: page 1 of  32
=====
```

it is clear that `Sections(idxsec).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes` does not find shape in the section only, on the other hand, it finds all shape in the doc

3. to simulate what human eyes read from header, I have to judge which one, text or text_in_shape, should be placed first. But

```
? ActiveDocument.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes(1).left
```

returns

```
-999996
```

which is a strange number for coordinate.

Aha, it is a tedious problem to read header's information which can be read by people.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: This strange value of left is from the [WdShapePosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdshapeposition) enumeration.

Answer (score 0):

1. You get the error because your code is trying to access a non-existent shape in the main body of the document. To access a shape in a header or footer you need to use code like you use in item 2
2. Your code is printing the total number of shapes in the header, not the shape number. Your code should be:

   ```
   Sub getShapeNumber()
       NumSections = ActiveDocument.Sections.Count
       For idxsec = 1 To NumSections
           With ActiveDocument.Sections(idxsec).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
               numShape = .Shapes.Count
               For idxShape = 1 To numShape
                   txt = "section " & idxsec & ", shape " & idxShape & ": "
                   txt = txt & .Shapes(idxShape).TextFrame.TextRange.Text
                   Debug.Print txt
               Next
           End With
       Debug.Print "====="
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: why shape 3 and 4 is in section 1; and shape 1 and 2 in section 2?

Comment: @oyster - because you evidently have 4 shapes in the header for those sections.